# The type command can't distinguish between an executable command and a shell script

Tags: shell, shell-script, command-line, executable, shell-builtin

So I was reading the book *The Linux Command Line*, and it says that commands are of four types:

> (1) executable programs
>
> (2) shell builtins
>
> (3) shell functions (shell scripts)
>
> (4) aliases

Then it says that in order to identify the type of a command, you can use the `type` command.

However, I noticed that the `type` command fails to distinguish between a shell function (shell script) and an executable command.

For example:

```
type cp
(will output: cp is /bin/cp)

type bzexe
(will output: bzexe is /bin/bzexe)
```

However, we all know that `cp` is an executable program and `bzexe` is a shell script.

So my question is now: what command can we use to differentiate between those two?

I do know about the `file` command, and it works fine. Is that the only solution?

Comment: A executable program is a file with the execute bit set on the file; if a shell script has that bit set, then to the os deems that file an executable program. That file actually doing something useful depend on other factors.

Comment: Does the book actually say "(3) shell functions (shell scripts)"?  That's horribly wrong.  If you use `bash-completion` in your interactive shells, you can see an example of a shell function by doing `type -a _pids`.  Running shell scripts from the shell isn't special.  You shouldn't normally *try* to `source` them instead of running them normally.  When you run them normally, it doesn't matter what language they're written in.  But yes, `file` is a good way to find out what kind of file something is if you're curious.

Answer (score 23):

A shell script *is* an executable program. That's why `type` says that it is one. A shell script is as much an executable command as a perl script, a python script, a native ELF executable, a cross-architecture executable being executed by Qemu through Linux's [binfmt_misc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc) mechanism, etc. Any executable file is an executable command, it doesn't matter what interpreter it uses.

As you can tell from my list of examples, the line between “a script” and “not a script” is fuzzy: any executable file that begins with a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) is a script, but there are executable files that are neither native code nor scripts.

When you execute a program, what language it's written in is irrelevant. So it wouldn't make sense for `type` to tell you about it. The job of `type` is only to tell you what type of command it is from the point of view of the shell.

A shell script is not the same thing as a function. A function runs inside the shell, and can modify the shell's environment. A shell script is a separate program; this separate program may happen to be written in the same language as the program you're running right now, but that's just a coincidence.

Answer (score 7):

The command you're wanting is `file`.

```
type /bin/bash
/bin/bash is /bin/bash

file /bin/bash
/bin/bash: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, stripped

type /bin/zcat
/bin/zcat is /bin/zcat

file /bin/zcat
/bin/zcat: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
```

EDIT: Sorry, I just read the last line of your post.  `file` isn't the only option but it's probably the best.  You could also use something like `head` to see if the file is plain text or binary but that's going to get messy fast :)

Comment: The best way is `file "$(which cp)"` so you can do it in one command without knowing the path.